# Chrome Headless - Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I'm using Window and I want to use the Chrome Headless with Watir Automation. I have the following code in my Hooks file but when I run the script I'm getting the error message below:

```
Before do
   @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
   @browser.goto "www.somewebsite.com"       
end
```

Error Message:   `Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout`

I have downloaded the latest ChromeDriver  v2.34 and the browser v63. 
See my Gemfile here:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b526bf12ce744fedf38b0cca38693e0

Comment: I get a DNS error for www.somewebsite.com. Are you sure that the actual url you are using is not timing out?

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the website url.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message even with www.google.com

Comment: First, remove watir-webdriver from your gemfile. Your code works if you remove the {headless: true} parameter? You get a ReadTimeout when a site takes too long to load, so it is typically a network issue.

Comment: I have removed watir-webdriver from the gemfile. It does work when I remove the (headless:true). It just doesn't work when I include the headless. Any solution to this?

Comment: This error seems cause by URL start with https://